# position div in a cell

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
top: 10px;
left: 30px;
background-color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width='500' border='1'>
<tr>
     <td height='300' width='250'></td>
     <td height='300' width='250'><div>content</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I position the div 10/30px to the top/left of the *right cell*?
I also want the cell grows with div, if size of div exceed that of the cell.

Thanks,
Cheng

Comment: try margin-left and margin-top

Comment: That would likely also work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 30px;
```

However this is bad use of markup for presentation. Dont use tables for placement.

Comment: Looks like an example page so that might not be the case. But I agree. Also, use CSS instead of the attributes width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` on the cell, and `position: absolute;` on the div.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` on the div

```
div
{
top: 10px;
left: 30px;
background-color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
}
```

By default `valign` of td is center, you might want to set it to `top`

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mP6wT/)

Comment: is there any way the cell can grow with div, right now the size of div can exceed that of the cell

Comment: Remove the height which you have given to the cell, it will grow as the inner div grows.

Comment: Do you want the div to go out? If yes, then set the height to td.